# Update tables which are present in the column using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a view which consist of number of tables as shown below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cols.referenced_entity_name AS TablesName
from
sys.sql_expression_dependencies objs
outer apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ( OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objs.referencing_id) + N'.' + object_name(objs.referencing_id), N'OBJECT' ) as cols
where
objs.referencing_id = object_id('ViewName')
```

I will get this:

```
TablesName
--------------------------------
table12345654-23232-233
table32423432-23233-232
table232323213-3213-232
```

**Question**:
  How can I update these tables?

Comment: How and what would you like to update about those tables? Same column name with same value, or variating column names with variating values? If the first, you can use dynamic SQL to generate update commands rather easily. If the latter, you need to figure out a query to get the variable values for each table, column and values you want to update. Point being, we don't have enough information to give a proper answer. Give an example of what kind of an update you're looking for, specifically. :)

Comment: @Kahn, Yup! I solved my problem with the help of dynamic query. Thanks :)